# VBS file not printing

Tags: vbscript, fso

I am new to VBS and I am trying to create a script that sorts some files in a folder and, if conditions are met, should output a MsgBox as well as printing the file. The MsgBox part works but the printing functionality doesn't work. Thanks for any guidance.

```
Option Explicit
Dim today_date, path
today_date = Date
path = "C:\Users\MyComputer\Desktop\FORMS"
Call GetRecentFile(path)


Function GetRecentFile(specify_path)
  Dim fso, file, my_counter
  my_counter = 0
  Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
  For Each file In fso.GetFolder(specify_path).Files
      If CDate(FormatDateTime(file.DateLAstModified, vbShortDate)) = Date Then
         file.InvokeVerbEx ("Print")
         my_counter = my_counter + 1

      End If
  Next

  If my_counter = 1 Then
     MsgBox "There is a new  file in the folder: " & path, 0, "ATTENTION !"
  ElseIf my_counter > 1 Then
     MsgBox "There are " & my_counter & "file in the folder: " & path, 0, "ATTENTION !"
  Else: MsgBox "There are no new files as of " & Now, 0, "NOTIFICATION"
  End If    


End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InvokeVerbEx` is a method of the `ShellFolderItem` object:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shellfolderitem-object

In your example script, the `file` variable is simply a `File` object (obtained through `Scripting.FileSystemObject`), not a `ShellFolderItem` object.

One way to obtain a `ShellFolderItem` object is to use `Shell.Application`, then call the `NameSpace` method using the current folder, then call its `ParseName` method using the file name.

For example, try replacing your line 14 `file.InvokeVerbEx ("Print")` with:

```
    With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        With .NameSpace(specify_path)
            With .ParseName(file.Name)
                .InvokeVerbEx("Print")
            End With
        End With
    End With
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using wsShell.Run file to open notepad and let the end user print; because the file needed to be printed in landscape mode and I am note sure if Notepad had any sendkeys command.

```
Option Explicit
Dim today_date, path
today_date = Date
path = "C:\Users\MyComputer\Desktop\FORMS"
Call GetRecentFile(path)

Function GetRecentFile(specify_path)
  Dim fso, file, my_counter,wsShell
  my_counter = 0
  Set wsShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
  Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
  For Each file In fso.GetFolder(specify_path).Files
      If CDate(FormatDateTime(file.DateLAstModified, vbShortDate)) = Date Then
         my_counter = my_counter + 1
         wShell.Run File

      End If
  Next

  If my_counter = 1 Then
     MsgBox "There is a new  file in the folder: " & path, 0, "ATTENTION !"
  ElseIf my_counter > 1 Then

    MsgBox "There are " & my_counter & "file in the folder: " & path, 0, "ATTENTION !"

  Else: MsgBox "There are no new files as of " & Now, 0, "NOTIFICATION"

  End If    


End Function
```